# How to Improve a repetitive Code

Tags: java

I am Trying to Turn on and off a set of 20 lights in a 3 color combination

the Combination goes RED GREEN WHITE

RGW RGW RGW RGW RGW RGW RG

Currently, I have hard coded a repetitive Sequence But was wondering on how to improve it. (P.S Beginning the journey to Learning JAVA).

I would like to know what method or practice I could learn to use in order to shorten this piece of code.

```
     if ( Num == 1){
        System.out.println("RED is On");//1
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Red is Off");

        System.out.println("Green is On");//2
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Green is Off");

        System.out.println("White is On");//3
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("White is OFF");

        System.out.println("RED is On");//4
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Red is Off");

        System.out.println("Green is On");//5
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Green is Off");

        System.out.println("White is On");//6
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("White is OFF");

        System.out.println("RED is On");//7
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Red is Off");

        System.out.println("Green is On");//8
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Green is Off");

        System.out.println("White is On");//9
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("White is OFF");

        System.out.println("RED is On");//10
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Red is Off");

        System.out.println("Green is On");//11
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Green is Off");

        System.out.println("White is On");//12
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("White is OFF");

        System.out.println("RED is On");//13
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Red is Off");

        System.out.println("Green is On");//14
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Green is Off");

        System.out.println("White is On");//15
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("White is OFF");

        System.out.println("RED is On");//16
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Red is Off");

        System.out.println("Green is On");//17
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Green is Off");

        System.out.println("White is On");//18
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("White is OFF");

        System.out.println("RED is On");//19
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Red is Off");

        System.out.println("Green is On");//20
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Green is Off");

    }
```

Comment: First ask yourself "what's the difference" (in each chunk of code)

Comment: I would assume you don't know about loops yet. If so, learn about them and use those.

Comment: You can use for loop for reduce your java code.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html might help

Comment: Use a loop, a method, or even both.

Answer (score 3):

Here one of many possibilities to do it in an infinite loop:

```
String[] color = new String[]{"Red", "Green", "White"};
int counter = 0;
while (true) {
    System.out.println(color[counter] + " is On");
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
    System.out.println(color[counter] + " is Off");

    counter++;

    if (counter > 2) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this - it's very concise.

Comment: I would do, `counter = counter%2`

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas Depending on how long it ran, you'd have to reset once you got to the maximum integer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of repetitiveness here:

1. You repeat *almost* the same code, but with a small thing changed (the colour)
2. Later you repeat chunks of code *exactly*, over and over again

The solution to (1) is to extract the repeated code into a method, with the changing element passed in as a parameter:

```
 private void flash(String color) {
    System.out.println(color + " is On");
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
    System.out.println(color + " is Off");
 }
```

Then call it as required:

```
 flash("Green");
 flash("RED");
 flash("White");
 // etc.
```

The solution to (2) is to express the repetition using a loop.

Your code seems to repeat red-green-white, so you can call `flash()` in a `for` loop:

```
 for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {   // 5 picked arbitrarily
     flash("RED");
     flash("Green");
     flash("White");
 }
```

You can even put a loop inside a loop:

```
 List<String> colors = Arrays.asList("RED", "Green", White");
 for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {   // 5 picked arbitrarily
     for(String color : colors) {
         flash(color);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the string 'colors' to blinker() as a parameter to make it reusable. Guessing from your conditional at the very top of your code I assume you'll have more than one pattern to blink. In that case for each pattern define a separate string 'colors' and once the pattern is requested -- feed it to the blinker(). Your code will be both readable and easy to maintain.

```
public void blinker() {


    String colors = "GWB GWB GWB GW GW GWWWW GWBB BWG";


    for (char c : colors.toCharArray()) {
        String colorName;
        switch (c) {
            case 'G':
                colorName = "GREEN";
                break;
            case 'W':
                colorName = "WHITE";
                break;
            case 'B':
                colorName = "BLUE";
                break;
            case ' ':
                continue;
            default:
                System.err.println("Unknown color: " + c);
                continue;
        }
        try {
            doBlink(colorName, 500);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }

}

public void doBlink(String color, long duration) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s is On", color));
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(duration);
    System.out.println(String.format("%s is Off", color));
}
```

And output looks like:

```
GREEN is On
GREEN is Off
WHITE is On
WHITE is Off
BLUE is On
BLUE is Off
GREEN is On
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one more:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String [] args){        
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).forEach(i->{
            try {
                onOff(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });        
    }

    private static void onOff(int i) throws InterruptedException {
        String color = getColor(i);
        System.out.println(color+" is On");
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        System.out.println(color+" is Off");
    }

    private static String getColor(int i) {
        return i%3 == 1? "RED": i%3 == 2? "Green" : "White";
    }
}
```